# Magento 1.8.x cron stopped

Tags: magento, cron

I've just upgraded my magento install with version 1.8.0.0 fron magento connect.

I’ve upgraded magento to 1.8.0.0 using “Magento connect” and since then the following message appeared

```
Cronjob status: Cron.php doesn’t seem to be set up properly. Cron did not execute within the last 15 minutes. Please make sure to set up the cronjob as explained here and check the cron status 15 minutes after setting up the cronjob properly again.
```

All scheduled jobs (stock import/order export, log cleaning, ...) have stopped since the upgrade.

my crontab is:

```
$ crontab -l
*/5 * * * * wget  -O /dev/null -q http://localhost/cron.php > /dev/null
```

and manually executing wget from a shell

```
wget  -O /dev/null -q -S http://localhost/cron.php 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Thu, 26 Sep 2013 07:10:10 GMT
  Server: Apache
  X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.21 ZendServer/5.0
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Content-Type: text/html
```

I've installed Aoe scheduler which shows a long list of pending jobs

No errors anywhere (apache logs, magento logs, ...)

How can I resolve this?

Thank you.

UPDATE: calling the shell script re-activated the hearthbeat ... still I cannot understand where the problem is

```
*/5 * * * * /var/www/magento/htdocs/cron.sh > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/609113/#t462030

I have the same problem, after I upgrade to 1.8.0.0 my cron is dead.

- Edit file cron.php
- After `$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, ‘win’) === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;` around #47 add this line of code

  `$isShellDisabled = true;`

Comment: Yes @Irkwz, I found that solution from your post in Magento forum. Thanks so much to you anyway :)

Comment: This answer helped me. I am using the following condition: if (stripos(php_sapi_name(), 'cgi') !== false) $isShellDisabled = true;;

Answer (score 1):

There's a file in the root of your Magento folder named

```
cron.php
```

This is the file run by your systems unix cron which manages Magento's cron jobs.  In other words, your system runs this `cron.php` file every minute, and this file checks Magento's cron configuration, and runs any jobs that are scheduled.

For some reason, this command isn't running in your system.  That means someone either removed `cron.php` from your system's `crontab`, or when the command runs there's an error.

Try jumping on your server and running the command yourself

```
$ php cron.php
```

My guess if you'll see an error of some kind.  This error is the reason your cron jobs aren't running.  Fix it, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: @lrkwz Run the cron.php script from the command with the server's built in PHP CLI program.  Fetching/running the script with wget or curl may suppress the errors.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion @alan-storm; tried this also with no luck, no errors nor warn from php cron.php or cron.sh